# image button is not displayed in linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app there is a list view with following controls (imageview, textviews, image buttons) nested:

[image]

all they are displayed except the "Buy" image button

[image]

How to show the "Buy" image button in the list view?
I also could not write an action for play and detail image buttons in the list view. Please help me.

my xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"  android:background="#ffffff">
     <ListView android:id="@+id/list" android:layout_width="1px"
    android:layout_height="1px" android:layout_weight="1">
     </ListView>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#ffffff">   

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">   
               <ImageView android:id="@+id/img" android:layout_width="60dp"
                  android:layout_height="60dp" />
        </LinearLayout> 

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="fffff"                
                android:id="@+id/title" android:singleLine="false"   android:layout_marginRight="20dp"  android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView  android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:text="dskbdskkdsvsvsvvvfff"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_marginRight="20dp" android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                       android:id="@+id/title2"/>            
            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ImageButton android:background="@drawable/play_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1">
            </ImageButton>
            <ImageButton android:background="@drawable/details_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" android:id="@+id/imageButton2">
            </ImageButton>
        </LinearLayout>            
        </LinearLayout> 
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="left">
                   <ImageButton android:background="@drawable/buy_btn"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:id="@+id/imageButton3">
                   </ImageButton>
           </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hi, i think that is preferable to work with a RelativeLayout

Comment: can you share your ideas. can i control text growth via relative layout?

Comment: You should redesign your entire layout. The way you have it right now it is very inefficient.

Comment: Tell us something if it works or not.. it gives us some idea abt our own answer or to know more..:-)

Comment: i get solution for display image. how to write action for image button  please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out with this and see. I have modified your xml. Drawables please change. I have used the default icon.png as of now. Then as per your any further requirement change the file. RelativeLayout is the easiest way for us to place widgets. So try using that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/img" android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icon" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img" android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textLL"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="fffff"
            android:id="@+id/title" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="dskbdskkdsvsvsvvvfff dfsdfg sdrfsdgfsdf dfsdfdsf dsgfsdfgg"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/title2" />

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageButton android:background="@drawable/icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2" android:layout_weight="0.5" />

            <ImageButton android:background="@drawable/icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton3" android:layout_weight="0.5" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton android:background="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textLL" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks your is work perfect.in the image view i hard code the size of the image as 60 X 60dp. actual size is 250 x 140. how to reduce the image size to thumb nail size.

Comment: how to write action for image button

Comment: write an onClick() for image btn

Comment: thanks in the image view i hard code the size of the image as 60 X 60dp. actual size is 250 x 140. how to reduce the image size to thumb nail size. because if i run in various resolution device, design may get vary.

Comment: @Mathew hi, your xml is works.but in the list view the action(toast does not shown) is does not work with the xml and if i remove all Image Buttons(Except text view and Image view) the action is works(toast shown). please check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288279/action-listener-is-not-work-in-list-view-in-android. please help me.