# action listener is not work in list view in android

Tags: android, android-layout

in my app i list video thumb nail from sdcard and image buttons and text view in a list view.
with out image buttons in the list view  action listener is work but i add image buttons in the list view the action listener((toast does not show)) does not work.

my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="100dp"
android:background="#ffffff">

   <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:id="@+id/Thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Thumbnail" android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textLL"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="fffff"
        android:id="@+id/FilePath" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="25dp"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="dskbdskkdsvsvsvvvfff"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/title2" />

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton android:background="@drawable/play_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2" android:layout_weight="0.5" />

        <ImageButton android:background="@drawable/details_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3" android:layout_weight="0.5" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
     <ImageButton android:background="@drawable/buy_btn"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:id="@+id/imageButton1" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textLL"/>
```

if i remove(image buttons) the following from xml the action listener(toast shown) is work.

```
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton android:background="@drawable/play_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2" android:layout_weight="0.5" />

        <ImageButton android:background="@drawable/details_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3" android:layout_weight="0.5" />

    </LinearLayout>
    and 
     <ImageButton android:background="@drawable/buy_btn"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:id="@+id/imageButton1" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textLL"/>
```

if i add the above(imageButtons) in the xml action listener does not work  i do not know what is the problem with my xml layout. please help me.

my code:

```
public class AndroidThumbnailList extends ListActivity{
    ..........
   public class MyThumbnaildapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
     public MyThumbnaildapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,String[] objects) {
       super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
     }
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         .........
     } 
 }

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    Log.e("video", "called");
    String selection = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), selection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      _contentUri = MEDIA_EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
      initVideosId();
      setListAdapter(new MyThumbnaildapter(AndroidThumbnailList.this, R.layout.row,  _videosId));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add android:focusable="false" to ImageButton.
Then add android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" to ImageButton's parent view. In your xml is LinearLayout and RelativeLayout.

Comment: thanks your code is works(toast is shown). how can i write individual action for each image button within the  
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
 ............
} please help me.